# Irreversibly Blocking Internet Access for an Hour

Tags: applications, wi-fi

I need something like an app with a switch that I can press so that my Android phone would be blocked from connecting to the internet (whether Wi-Fi or mobile data) for an hour so that I may focus on things such as cleaning the house, reading books, or studying. Most importantly, the switch should be enforced and irreversible. I should be unable to connect back to the internet unless an hour has elapsed after pressing it. This is for self-control reasons. Non-rooted.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this is a time-locked container. These are already sold, for purposes including mobile phone addiction. Examples from my local Amazon store, since I don't know which country you're in: [Vaydeer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BNN9HTP5/), or [Mplerven](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Multi-Purpose-Container-Addiction-Excessive-Properly/dp/B07XKMZXL7/).

Doing this with software on the device is not dependable if you don't trust yourself: what software can do, it can undo.